# Paging not properly working Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My pagination not properly working it have some problems

Here is my controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$query= $this->db->get('invoice','5', $this->uri->segment(3));
$data['invoices']=$query->result();
//enter code here       
$query2=$this->db->get('invoice');
$config['base_url'] = '/dashboard/billing';
$config['total_rows'] =$query2->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 5;

$config ['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config ['full_tag_close']='</ul>'; 

$config ['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link ">';
$config ['last_tag_open']='<li class="page-item page-link">';

$config ['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link ">';
$config ['perv_tag_open']='<li>';

$config ['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link">';
$config ['num_tag_close']='</li>';

$config ['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config ['last_tag_close']='</li>';

$config ['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config ['perv_tag_close']='</li>';

$config ['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active page-link ">';
$config ['cur_tag_close']='</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$this->pagination->create_links();

$this->load->view('dash_billing',$data);
```

And i am transferred that $data into view and run with foreach loop
i getting some error like

1)not able to click Page 1 (actually it opened in 2nd page)

[image: 1st one]
2)page last 2,3 can be click

3)Next button only work once

4)when i click last button i can see all other link but not properly working

[image: 4th One]

Comment: you have your get() wrong http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: Datas fetching fine if i put page number at the end of the url, and also work when i click page 2,3 and last

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

I solved with  this line of code

$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;